# SQL Bulk Insert - ROWTERMINATOR 'Ox0A' vs '\r\n'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL job to replace some old legacy processing.  Basically, it reads in a raw text file, does some manipulations to the data, then runs an update statement.  Pretty simple.  However, I ran into an issue with the BULK INSERT and I don't exactly understand the resolution, so I wanted to post it here.

The BULK INSERT statement I was writing was as follows:

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
BULK INSERT [SomeTableName] FROM '\\FILE_PATH_HERE\test.txt'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'--'\r\n'
);
```

When I ran original statement with the ROWTERMINATOR of '\r\n' no data was populated in my table.  When I replaced '\r\n' with 'OxOa' my bulk insert worked.

The reason I am unsure why this worked, is that when I view file in Notepad++ with View->Symbols->Show all characters, I see CRLF at the end of each data line.  I thought that '\r\n' was the equivalent of a carriage return line feed (CRLF), but it wasn't working.  I thought 'Oxoa' only represented a '\n' so I am a little unsure why changing ROWTERMINATOR from '\r\n' to '0x0a' worked.

Any insight would be appreciated

Comment: AFAIK the behavior you describe should not happen.  Can you provide a download or hex dump of a file that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft
How would I go about providing a download for you to access?  That is something I have never done on SO before

Comment: You could put the hex dump in your question body, or provide an anonymous download link to a file shared on OneDrive, Box, or similar.

Comment: I found the same problem. Only 0x0a and \n works, although Notepad++ shows CRLF. Guessing: could it be also because of UCS-2 format of the file and DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar'?

Answer (score 1):

That is because from '\r\n' is not '0x0a'.

\r is carriage return = 0D and
\n is line feed = 0A

Windows does tend to have CrLf
Whereas Linux tend to have just Lf.

Since just 0a worked, your file is likely generated from a Linux process.